# Creating an animated view under navigation bar

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, subview

In my app i want to add something similar to the animated view that appears and disappears under the navigation bar , similar to the Facebook Messanger one :

Comment: I have no code , i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Do you have already this bar or you just need the animation ?

Comment: I do not have the bar , i just want it to display a few labels. How can i create the view , make the animation work when pressing the button , and place it under the navbar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own view (Google it)

> UIView *yourCustomView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 0, 0, 200, 150)];

The two first 0,0 are for positioning
The two last numbers are for width and height

Add your custom to your main view

> [self.view addSubview:yourCustomView]

Add what you want in your custom view (label, buttons)
This quite the same than for UIView. (UILabel is an UIView)

Create an animation
[Create a view with Raywenderlinch](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation)

Then fire it with your IBAction from the button